# How would one Raid 0 two ssd's and effectively back them up to a HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid

So I've read a lot of similar questions, both here and elsewhere, and none of them quite answer my scenario.

I have 2 500GB SSDs and 1 1TB HDD. What I would like to do is RAID 0 the SSDs into a 1TB raid array. Of course this is volatile and when (not if) one of the SSDs finally goes kaput, I'd like to be able to break the array, replace the shot SSD(s), and create a new array which I would restore from the duplicate on the 1 TB HDD.

Now I thought about a RAID 01 situation, 0 on SSDs and 1 between the 0 array and the HDD, but logically that would make the SSD array as slow as the HDD, right? I obviously don't want that... So I'm kind of stumped on what a good solution might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stripe the two 500GB SSDs together to make a ~1TB RAID 0, however there is no way you can add the slower 1TB HDD into the array without slowing the SSDs down.

Your best bet would be a volume shadow copy backup solution that images the SSD array to the 1TB HDD.  You can run the backups as often as you feel necessary.  This method will allow you to keep the speed of the SSDs, while only slowing them down slightly for the backup to read the disks.  There are many programs out there that will do volume shadow copy based image backups.  You can do incremental images to speed the process as well.

Comment: Intriguing, I wonder if Acronis boot disk could handle this. Any chance you could expand your answer slightly more with an example of some software that would be capable?

Comment: Comodo Backup does this, I believe Macrium Reflect as well

Answer (score 1):

There really is no way to keep the performance of the SSDs if you create an array with the SSDs and the HDD.

I would recommend you create a RAID 1 on the SSDs for the operating system; say 60-80 GB min or so for windows, less for Linux.  Then create a RAID 0 of the remaining space on the SSDs for storage.

Then schedule a program like [Free File Sync](http://www.freefilesync.org/) to backup the files from the RAID 0 to the HDD on an interval of your liking.  Or you can use [Real Time Sync](http://www.freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=realtimesync) or equivalent to keep the RAID 0 and the HDD synced in realtime.  This effective means you would be RAID'ing the RAID 0 and HDD on a file level, not the block level.

This assumes you would store all of your user files and such on the RAID 0; not the default location on the RAID 1 with the OS.